# Multiple options and open search in the same field

Tags: search, input-fields, options

for a webapp I would like  a 'speed' search field in which users could search by concrete speeds in kilometers per hour km/h, and at the same time they should have the possibility to make a less accurate search by choosing between 'slow. medium, or fast'. So the possible searchs in that field would be

- slow
- medium
- fast
- xxx km/h

where xxx is any number (e.g- 60 km/h, 200 km/h)

What's the best solution for that?

Comment: Best solution for what? How user can select what kind of input they are going to provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you would like an easy to use way of searching for a speed, whether it's a vague description or a specific value.

Who is your audience?  Is it literally anyone, or is it older folks, or younger folks?

I think with older folks, a very obvious, clickable UI is more appreciated (but I think this UI choice is perfectly suitable for any situation).  For example, you could have something like:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX6tsq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

For a younger crowd, or a data-entry type situation where speed is important, you could go with an autocomplete box.  I think the autocomplete options should be immediately apparent when the field has focus - and/or a *very* small blurb needs to exist to let the users know what options are available:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKxmU0.png)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Do what Google does:

[image: Google exact and ballpark filter options]

It's clean, simple and unambiguous.